# Is it possible to secure the standard media endpoint in eve?

Tags: python, flask, eve

I would like to know if there's a way to require authentication to retrieve images stored in eve's API standard media endpoint. The `RETURN_MEDIA_AS_URL` is set to `True`, so by default images can be retrieved from the `/media` endpoint without any authentication after obtaining the image URL.

Comment: Did you check out eve docs. http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#endpoint-level-authentication

Comment: yes, I did. Did you find anything about this? I don't if you are familiar with eve, but the link you posted is not what I'm looking for. The media endpoint is a bit different.

Comment: Actually there is a auth class so docs says you can create custom authentication for your resource and I have tried. For example `/user/?id=23` first shows login alert if credentials are fine then I could get user info. Aren't you looking something similar?

Comment: Similar, but this works only for resources from your schema definition. When serving files, you do not have this schema definition. See here http://python-eve.org/features.html#file-storage.

Comment: So what about Global Endpoint Security? http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#global-endpoint-security

Comment: Global security is correct. It has no public methods configured. Seems it makes no difference in this case though.